# MVVM pattern necessarily needs a database?

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm

MVVM pattern necessarily needs a database? Because, all crud examples that I found do not use a database, they all do the CRUD inside the code, with list's and obsservableCollection's.
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to your question is no. The MVVM design pattern is a presentation model hence **independent** from a persistent data store. Consequently, you do **not** need a database. Read this for an introduction: [WPF Apps With The Model-View-ViewModel Design Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel).

What you do need though is a data model which forms part of the MVVM design pattern. The decision to use a database (or any other datastore) for [CRUD operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) of your data model (or parts of it) depends on the functional requirements of the application.

Answer (score 4):

No, MVVM Pattern is just a pattern(a reusable solution for a recurring problem). So it is an application necessity whether to have DAL(data access layer) or not.

MVVM consists three layers:
1. Model 2. ViewModel. 3. View

MVVM is short for Model-View-ViewModel.

Models are simple objects of classes that hold data( For example, Person, Animal or Tank classes). These classes should only contain properties and property validation. There are no responsibility for getting data, saving data, click events, complex calculations, business rules, or any of that stuff.

Views are the UI used to display data, what  user see and what user interact with. In most cases, they can be DataTemplates which is simply a template that tells the application how to display a class. It is OK to put code behind your view IF that code is related to the View only, such as setting focus or running animations.

ViewModels are classes where the magic happens. They send data to View by events(INotifyPropertyChanged). This is where the majority of your code-behind goes: data access, click events, complex calculations, business rules validation, etc. They are typically built to reflect a View. For example, if a View contains a ListBox of objects, a Selected object, and a Save button, the ViewModel will have an ObservableCollection ObectList, Model SelectedObject, and ICommand SaveCommand.

MVVM Pattern allows you separate data from view. Data is just data and view is just view. No dependency between data and view, so we have other advantages such as unit testing and loose coupling.